# thread 1: exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_i386_invop,subcode=0x0) /fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swift, xcode, multithreading

I'm trying to develop  an app and for now I'd like to edit the text of a label by the inputs of 2 different UIPickerViews.

At first I'd get the error.
`"thread 1: exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_i386_invop,subcode=0x0)"` 
pointing at a certain bit of code (see code) but now I only get the error 
`"fatal error: Index out of range"`

The problem is in the first picker, if I change anything there (in the simulator!) the app crashes. If I change the second picker only and then update the label it changes to '1 days' or '2 weeks', instead of only 'days' or 'weeks'.

My Storyboard:

[image: main.storyboard]

My code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var PickerView1: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var PickerView2: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func changeLabel(_ sender: UIButton) {
    outputLabel.text = outputTotal
}

var list1 = [""]
var list2 = [""]
var output1 = ""
var output2 = ""
var outputTotal = ""

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// Aangeven welke items er in de pickerview komen
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if (pickerView.tag == 1){
        return "\(list1[row])"
    } else {
        return "\(list2[row])"
    }
}

// Aantal rijen weergeven
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if (pickerView.tag == 1){
        return list1.count
    } else {
        return list2.count
    }
}

// Label veranderen naar input van PickerView1
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    output1 = list1[row]
    output2 = list2[row] // error points here
    outputTotal = output1 + " " + output2
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    list1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
    list2 = ["days", "weeks"]
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

If anyone can help me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to detect which `pickView` is selected in `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)`:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        output1 = list1[row]
    } else {
        output2 = list2[row]
    }
    outputTotal = output1 + " " + output2
}
```

Comment: Oh god that was actually extremely simple and now I feel stupid because I didn't see it.. Thanks a lot! ^^

Comment: you're welcome! and don't forget to accept my answer. thanks!